# Genymotion plugin that allows remote control of multiple virtual devices?

Tags: plugins, genymotion

I know the title is messed up and confused....because I am! :)  I am not too familiar with Genymotion and have never tried my hand at making an app.  I am using genymotion in an attempt to maximize my gaming pleasure.  Can't blame a dude.

So I was told that there is a plugin that allows one to say, open 10 instances of andrioid via virtual devices.  I can do this now no problem.  However to do the same thing on all 10 devices....takes forever.  I was told that with a plug in I could set one device...more specially i was told my own cell phone, plugged in via usb and have that be the 'control' device.  I would click somewhere on my device and in turn, all 10 on my pc screen would follow suite.

Anyone know which plugin to use for this and what the tech. term for this would be? I've been looking and can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks to all who took time to read.

Answer (score 0):

The Remote control plugin for Genymotion virtual devices is designed so that **one remote device will control one virtual device** and viceversa.

It is these way because the connection stabilized through adb interface is created between one procces in the remote/real device (in fact, Genymotion installs a custom app for these purpose on run time) and the virtual machine created for running Android.

If you want to use Remote control for Genymotion you need a pay account for enable the plugin in your virtual device configuration, or a Trial account which you can use complet functionality some days.